# Laravel Websockets events not firing

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I've implemented Laravel Websockets along with Echo in my local environment and everything is working, but when deploying to production, it appears a connection can be made and it's subscribed to the channels, but events do not fire. And I'm clueless about what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my setup:

`.env` file:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=someID
PUSHER_APP_KEY=someKey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=someSecret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_USE_SSL=false

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
MIX_PUSHER_USE_SSL=true
MIX_PUSHER_HOST=mydomain.com
MIX_PUSHER_PORT=443
```

`Echo` configuration:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
  cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
  wsHost: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_HOST,
  wsPort: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_PORT,
  forceTLS: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_USE_SSL === true || process.env.MIX_PUSHER_USE_SSL === 'true',
  disableStats: true,
});
```

`nginx` config:

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/app/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

location /apps/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/apps/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

This is to set up a reverse proxy to be able to use my site's SSL

`websockets.php` and `broadcasting.php` are left with all default values.

On the websockets dashboard at `/laravel-websockets` I am able to connect via port 443 and I can see it subscribed to my channels:

[image: websockets subscribed to channels]

What I expect to see when an event should be triggered is something like this that I see in my local environment:

[image: websockets api-message]

But this does not appear in production. As if it can subscribe to channels but not capture the `api-message` events.

This is my first time implementing websockets so I'm a little lost. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, figured it out!

What I didn't realize but makes perfect sense is that these API messages that get broadcast are queued. And if your queue is not consuming correctly, you'll never see them.

In my local environment I used Laravel's `sync` queue driver, so that's why it worked locally, but on in production due to a config error my RabbitMQ queue was not being consumed correctly.

Once I fixed that, everything started working as expected :)

Anyway maybe the configuration listed in my question will help someone else who's trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Lifesaver. Thanks! 
I was wondering why the events are not fired. Thanks to your post, I went to check the Jobs page in Telescope. Surely all the events were queued there with the status `pending` so never broadcast. 
To broadcast the events immediately without queuing them, I changed my event class interface implementation from: 

    class MyEvent implements ShouldBroadcast {}

to:

    class MyEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow {}

Problem sorted.

Comment: i didn't start the queue process, it drove me crazy i didn't know it was related. thanks

Comment: @chris what have you assigned to the QUEUE_CONNECTION? right now I have QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync.

Comment: @kamran in production I use `rabbitmq` to handle my queue, so it's set to that. You'd need to install the `vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq` package in order to be able to use rabbitmq

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to replace BROADCAST_DRIVER=log to BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher and then run php artisan optimize:clear